What dimensions to expect of Principal Components Analysis?
In both Python and R, the matrix of eigenvectors of Principal Component Analysis (PCA) is a matrix of principal components with dimensions (Number of Observations x Number of Principal Components). Since the eigenvalue decomposition is based on the variance-covariance matrix, which has dimensions (Number of Features x Number of Features), why is the resulting PCA matrix dimensioned as (Number of Observations x Number of Principal Components) instead? Could someone explain the reasoning behind this difference?

I'm guessing a result that is "Number of Observations x Number of Principal Components" is probably the principal component scores.
